# 2024-02-15 10:03:17.264 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 08c failed to invoke chaincode token-erc-721, error: container exited with 1

Tags: hyperledger, fabric

ehtasham@ehtasham-9876-1961A:~/fabric-samples/test-network$ ./network.sh deployCC -ccn token-erc-721 -ccp ../token-erc-721/chaincode-javascript/ -ccl javascript
deploying chaincode on channel 'mychannel'
executing with the following

- CHANNEL_NAME: mychannel
- CC_NAME: token-erc-721
- CC_SRC_PATH: ../token-erc-721/chaincode-javascript/
- CC_SRC_LANGUAGE: javascript
- CC_VERSION: 1.0
- CC_SEQUENCE: 1
- CC_END_POLICY: NA
- CC_COLL_CONFIG: NA
- CC_INIT_FCN: NA
- DELAY: 3
- MAX_RETRY: 5
- VERBOSE: false

- peer lifecycle chaincode package token-erc-721.tar.gz --path ../token-erc-721/chaincode-javascript/ --lang node --label token-erc-721_1.0
- res=0
  Chaincode is packaged
  Installing chaincode on peer0.org1...
  Using organization 1
- peer lifecycle chaincode install token-erc-721.tar.gz
- res=1
  Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': could not build chaincode: docker build failed: docker image build failed: docker build failed: Error returned from build: 1 "+ INPUT_DIR=/chaincode/input
- OUTPUT_DIR=/chaincode/output
- cp -R /chaincode/input/src/. /chaincode/output
- cd /chaincode/output
- '[' -f package-lock.json -o -f npm-shrinkwrap.json ]
- npm ci '--only=production'
  npm ERR! Cannot read property 'express' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-02-15T09_54_29_378Z-debug.log
"
Chaincode installation on peer0.org1 has failed
Deploying chaincode failed

I WANT TO deploye chain code on my channnel but i causing issues and i think its versions issue but i am not sure curretnly i am using using node v18.19.0 (npm v10.4.0).